# mongo.exe - Entry point not found

Tags: mongodb, windows-vista, dynamic-linking, entry-point, kernel32

I'm trying to set up a MEAN stack and I'm having the following issue when trying to execute mongo.exe: "The procedure entry point K32GetProcessMemoryInfo could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll"
I'm using Windows Vista 64bit, mongo is the latest, and I'm logged as administrator.
Thanks.

Comment: have you installed the 64Bit version of mongodb?

Comment: Installed with mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.6.5-signed msi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Vista you need to install the Legacy version of MongoDb.

> The 64-bit legacy build lacks newer features of Windows that enhance performance. Use this build for Windows Server 2003, 2008, or Windows Vista.

Here´s the [Download link](https://fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.6.5-signed.msi?_ga=1.81566355.525717268.1412755230)

Comment: Solved. Thanks Jehof.